# Controlling High Voltage device with Arduino

Tags: arduino, control, triac, solid-state-relay

I want to control lava lamps using Arduino. I think it shouldn't be hard project, but I have no experience with hardware projects so I'm not sure witch design will feet best for me.

I consider using S202T01 Series Solid State Relays (I already have two of them).  I think it's the easiest way to do it (Am I right?, Are my SSR good for that?). Probably I could use LED blinking example and use SSR instead of LEDs. I think there are some other advantages of this approach. It's safety because of optoisolation, and it can switch very fast. Unfortunately SSR are quiet expensive and I need control ten devices.

I'm looking for cheaper solution (but not much harder to use, and also safety). Me by I should use TRIACs (if yes what models)?

And one more question: how about cooling? Should I use radiator on Solid State Relays or TRIACs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend sticking with SSRs. You can get them for somewhat cheap from ebay or allelectronics.com.

But, if you want to use TRIACs, you can obviously do that as well. You will want to use an optoisolator to separate the high and low voltages. I found this (http://www.epanorama.net/circuits/semiconductor_relays.html) to be a very useful resource on how to use TRIACs as a relay/switch.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this thread on [arduino.cc forums](http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1236998971/0). Someone is in the process of developing a AC Shield for the arduino using TRIAC's.

Answer (score 2):

I would stick with the SSR's too. It will be less parts and the opto-isolation is already
built-in.